# Why am I gettitng ModuleNotFoundError when importing file in directory?

Tags: python, github, jupyter, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have opened a remote github repository in vs code that contains a project for uni. The structure of the project is as follows:

```
walking_panda
└──__init__.py
└── cli.py
└── panda.py
walking_panda.py
```

walking_panda.py contains the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from walking_panda.cli import cli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

When executing the file it returns this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'walking_panda'
```

Is there something wrong with my from statement, or is it to do with the fact that the files are in a remote repository and not actually stored on my computer? I am also running using the Jupyter Interactive extension on vs code if that makes any difference. Also using linux mint.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I am quiet sure that you need an (empty) `__init__.py` file in your base directory. So in the same folder as 'walking_panda'.

Comment: Yes i already have an `__init__.py` file in the walking_panda folder as shown in the project structure above.

Comment: Yes, inside the folder, but not in the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the file `walking_panda.py` is executed from another directory than the one it is located.
If you can modify it, try to add:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())
```

That should show from where `python` is called and if there is the module `walking_panda` in this same place. For info, the current working directory (where `python` is executed from) is inserted at index 0 of the `sys.path`, which lists all the directories where modules can be imported from.